# Why unix domain socket can be used to transfer fd from child to father?

Tags: sockets, unix, process, between

I know if a unix process forks, the child process can use fd from father. This is inheritance: but not vice versa.

While the unix advance programing materials say if we use unix domain socket, not only we can transfer a fd from child to father, but also between processes.

This is weird:

> an fd is only meaningful within one process, in different process, same fd value could mean very different.
>
> Then how could unix domain socket really transfer fds between processes? I mean the integer (4 bytes) can be transferred by any means, but it doesn't seem to make sence that one process can operate another process's fd?

Any explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really try that yourself. As it said in the man page of [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):

`SCM_RIGHTS
              Send or receive a set of open file descriptors from another
              process.  The data portion contains an integer array of the
              file descriptors.  The passed file descriptors behave as
              though they have been created with dup(2).`

that means the fds received are not equal to the ones sent as in numbers, they're like newly created fds, but they're actually the same thing in the kernel's perspective of view.